# How to set width property of Kendo UI button

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I need to set button's width programmatically. I've seen an example [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/button/index), which is based on using css style. However, it is now what I want. I want to have something like:

```
el.kendoButton({"width":"300"});
```

or:

```
el.kendoButton();
el.setWidth(300);
```

Is there something like that in Kendo library?? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use jquery

for all buttons

```
$(".k-button ").width(300);
```

for selective buttons, set your own class for those buttons

`$(".myButton").width(300);`

Comment: Didn't work for me - had to do it non-programatically ( http://jsfiddle.net/zacharydl/4QezZ/ ).

Comment: @GrahamLaight both are same

Comment: I'd like to have used your simpler method. Maybe it has to do with running after the buttons have already been rendered.